# In excel, searching for the first instance of an array of words in a cell

Tags: excel

I have a cell (bd5) with a long description of an event. I also have a list (Name Range= 'greeting') of things that should have happened early in the event. I want to know where in the cell (word count or character count) any of the array items first shows up.

=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(greeting,B2),greeting),"") gives me the actual word not its location in cell b2

```
    A                  B                                  c              
1   Greeting      Transcript                           Greeting count    
2   My Name is    This is a long transcription of       Thank you for
                  a call. My agent should be starting   calling
                  with either "Thank you for Calling' 
                  or 'Good afternoon' before they pull
                  up the caller;s information and 
                  start troubleshooting
3   How May I 
    help you
4   Good morning
5   Good Afternoon
6   Thank you for 
    calling
```

I tried to recreate the example sheet. If I enter the formula I used above in C2 it results in "Thank you for calling" However I need to know where it falls in b2 . So a 16 would be best because it is the 16th word. However, 84 would as a character location.

Comment: Can you please show some sample data, and sample expected output?  You might just need to include using `Search()`/`Find()`.

Comment: how do I upload here

Comment: Copy some data, paste to your original post (and if it's a table, you can format it with the code tags `{}`).  But please don't actually upload a file, I (and others I can assume) aren't likely to download random files).

Comment: I copied the data and rtried to paste it. (It's part of an excel file) It want's to save it as an image. and then tells me I can't uplaoad images yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's an unfortunate side-effect of the new layout. (I even have [a Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320162/cant-paste-data-to-question-get-prompted-for-image) on this).  Copy the data to Notepad/something, then you should be able to paste here.  Or try pasting with CTRL+SHIFT+V.

Comment: I have added a mock up of the spread sheet to my original question.  To be clear A2:A6 is my List Name 'greeting'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your data, I get 82 for the position of the matched string:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH($A$2:$A$6,B2),1)
```

To get a word number (16 in your example) where the matched text is found:

```
=LEN(LEFT(B2,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH($A$2:$A$6,B2),1)))+1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH($A$2:$A$6,B2),1))," ",""))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to have to research Aggregate to see how that worked.

Comment: I found a few that didn't have the terms and get a #NUM error. Would wrapping this in an IFERROR statement resolve it?

Comment: @JimBrockman Yes.  And `AGGREGATE` provides a way of ignoring the errors for the non-matching items in the Greetings list.